# Sort the directories and files in each directory in ascending order and export data to csv

Tags: shell-script, text-processing, sort, csv

I have 30 directories i have more than 300 text files in each, all text files in each directory have same naming format

```
regional_vol_GM1.txt
regional_vol_GM2.txt
regional_vol_GM*.txt
```

I would like to sort the directories and text files in sequential order and export the data in each file into csv file

Following is the script i have written

```
for dir in * ; do


   paste -s -d ',' <(tail -q -n 1 "$dir"/t1/regional_vol*.txt ) >> data.csv

 done
```

The output csv file that i obtain is unsorted, how can sort all the files in my directory in ascending order and export the data to csv

Comment: glob expansions are sorted lexically on file names by default. If you want a different sorting order, please be more explicit.

Comment: If your problem is that for instance GM10 comes before GM2 in lexical order, you could switch to using `zsh` with its numerical glob sorting options: `for dir in *(/n)` and `..regional_col*.txt(n)`.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas Exactly , my problem is directory GM10 comes before GM2 but i dont have zsh , is there any way to solve this in bash ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your problem is that the order is lexical instead of being numerical, you could use `zsh` and do:

```
for dir in *(n/); do
  tail -q -n 1 "$dir"/t1/regional_vol*.txt(n) | paste -s -d ',' -
done > data.csv
```

The `n` glob qualifier causes the sorting to be numerical.

If using `zsh` is not an option but your `ls` is the GNU one, an alternative is to use GNU `ls`'s `-v` option for *version* sort:

```
eval "dirs=($(ls -v --quoting-style=shell-always))"
for dir in "${dirs[@]}"; do
  eval "files=($(
    ls -vd --quoting-style=shell-always -- "$dir"/t1/regional_vol*.txt))"
  tail -q -n 1 -- "${files[@]}" | paste -sd , -
done > data.csv
```

Yes, that's [parsing the output of `ls`](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs) and [using `eval`](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/048) in the same command!

But here, it's safe as `ls` with `--quoting-style=shell-always` outputs in the exact format expected by `eval`.

To add your row and column headers:

```
{
  eval "dirs=($(ls -v --quoting-style=shell-always))"
  headers_done=false
  for dir in "${dirs[@]}"; do
    (
      cd -- "$dir/t1" || exit
      eval "files=($(
        ls -vd --quoting-style=shell-always regional_vol*.txt))"
      if ! "$headers_done"; then
        printf DIR
        printf ',%s' "${files[@]}"
        printf '\n'
        headers_done=true
      fi
      printf %s, "$dir"
      tail -q -n 1 -- "${files[@]}" | paste -sd , -
    )
  done
} > data.csv
```

Comment: Thanks it works greatly,Is there any way i can export file name of each file in directory as the name of row like this [expected result](http://imgur.com/vfQiMQK) , since all 30 directories have .txt files of same file names, i just need a one single row which consists of all files names in directory , i have added this line to code:  paste -d, $(ls -1v "$dir"/t1/regional_vol*.txt ) > data.csv, but i dont see file names of each file in the first row

Comment: @DevanDev, replace `$(` with `<(` in your command.

Comment: I did that ,The output i am getting is incorrect [output](http://imgur.com/rjWCTff) , This is the format of output that i would like to obtain [Desired result](http://imgur.com/vwr39vb),  what i need is the first row of csv should be the file names arranged in sequential order  like regional_vol_GM1.txt ,regional_vol_GM2.txt ..etc . and first column of csv should be directory name like Sub1,Sub2..Sub30. I have 30 directories with naming convention Sub1,Sub2,Sub30

Comment: @DevanDev, see  edit

Comment: Thanks a lot works great, except minute issue, in the [output file](http://imgur.com/AXQuTsp)  on the top row i just need regional_vol_GM.txt instead of subject1/t1/regional_vol_GM.txt

Comment: @DevanDev, see edit.